# Node-Fetch gives ERR_INVALID_URL for a static file

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use fetch api for fetching data from a static file, which gives me the error:

input: 'data.txt',

code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL'

I am running the code from within VSCODE PowerShell with node. I installed the node-fetch module because node doesnt support fetch api by default. The data.txt is in the same path/directory.

```
import fetch from "node-fetch"
function getText() {
  fetch("data.txt").then(function (res) {
    console.log(res);
  });
}
getText()
```

Comment: Out of interest, why not use the fs library to read the file?

Comment: just trying fetch api... any idea why its not working?